# Looping over all documents in an elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

Using the Elasticsearch javascript client (node.js), what is the best (or simplest) way to loop through every document in an index (ca. 100 000 documents)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think a good place to start is with scan queries using the scroll api:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Basically it's similar to a cursor with a database - you open the query with a time limit and it returns a scroll id. You then use that scroll id to retrieve the first batch of results and it returns the documents along with a new scroll id. Examples below:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=10m&size=1000' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}
'
```

This will return a _scroll_id that you then use to retrieve documents:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=10m' -d '<_SCROLL_ID_HERE>'
```

Note that this will return 1000 documents PER PRIMARY SHARD - so if you have 4 primary shards it will return 4000 documents. Each call will in addition to the documents return a new _scroll_id which you then use for the next call. The "scroll=10m" sets a time limit of 10m to keep the scroll open between calls.

Comment: This answer is now old. The above doc page says: "
We no longer recommend using the scroll API for deep pagination. If you need to preserve the index state while paging through more than 10,000 hits, use the search_after parameter with a point in time (PIT)."